# Why is zookeeper gem install failing with "variable ‘port’ set but not used" on Ubuntu 12.04 - GCC 4.6.3?

Tags: ruby, gcc, rubygems, apache-zookeeper

Zookeeper on a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 is failing.

src/zookeeper.c: In function ‘getaddrs’:
src/zookeeper.c:455:13: error: variable ‘port’ set but not used [-Werror=unused-but-set-variable]

Comment: Turns out its a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1117. Short term solution for me was to just apt-get install gcc-4.5 and point gcc to gcc-4.5 instead of 4.6 and after that i was able to install no problem. I then pointed back to 4.6...latest is greatest!...well kinda

Comment: You may switch to a lower version of gcc/g++(4.4.x is ok) or compile the zookeeper lib in lower version of gcc/g++ environment and copy it to your Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's a known issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-1117. Short term solution for me was to just `apt-get install gcc-4.5` and point gcc to gcc-4.5 instead of 4.6 and after that I was able to install with no problem. I then pointed back to 4.6...latest is greatest!...well kinda

I am answering my own question so that an answer could be accepted for this question. Although, this is only a short term solution.